# Can't enable dev module from Drush

Tags: 7, drush

I am downloading a dev version of the [Drush Search & Replace](https://www.drupal.org/project/sar) module via

`drush dl sar-7.x-2.x-dev`

And then trying to enable it

`drush en sar`

But returns contradicting options. First it says the project was not found, and then asks to overwrite the project that was downloaded previously

```
drush en sar
sar was not found.                                                                                                                   [warning]
The following projects provide some or all of the extensions not found:                                                              [ok]
sar
Would you like to download them? (y/n): y
Install location /home/ubuntu/.drush/sar already exists. Do you want to overwrite it? (y/n):
```

Using drush 5.10.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear drush cache.  I have seen this same thing before, where I try to do a drush action from a module and am told the action is not available.  Then a `drush pm-list | grep "module"` shows me it is enabled.

```
drush cc drush
drush en sar
```

As we say around my office daily, "When in doubt, clear cache."  If this is not working, then take a step back and verify your assumptions.

We assume the download succeeded, so we should be able to find the module in a "not installed" state.  Verify with drush:

```
drush pm-list | grep "sar"
```

We assume drush handled the download properly, try again with another folder.  Verify with drush:

```
drush dl sar --destination="sites/all/modules"
```

**Solution:**

I assumed, since you were asking about enabling, that this was a site module.  After downloading it on my local system I see that this is a drush command package, and that `[user]/.drush/sar` is correct.  Verify the module does not need enabled and is already working with:

```
drush help sar
```

Comment: Just tried that, but hasn't seemed to have any effect unfortunately. Have a feeling it's the old drush version, will look into upgrading

Comment: do you see sar listed with `drush pm-list | grep "sar"` ?

Comment: I didn't unfortunately

Comment: @JosephYoung this kind of module does not need enabled.